# GNN Model - Analyzing Training Curve

Tags: deep-learning, machine-learning-model, convolutional-neural-network, data-science-model, graph-neural-network

**Introduction.** Actually, I am working on a Graph Neural Network (GNN) model to predict some graph-level float values. So, input=graph, output=float predicted value. I trained and evaluated the proposed model with the below structure and the training curve is illustrated. **The problem is** the validate curve fluctuates and it does not converge well to the training curve.

**Dataset Info.**
My dataset consists of ~20K graph samples such that each graph has its own size(in terms of #nodes, #edges), and each node in each graph has its own feature value. Note that, the size of features (X_vi) of all nods in all graphs is constant).

- Number of samples: 18570.
- Number of output: 1.
- Number of edge features: 2.
- Number of node features: 7.
- Num of training samples 14856 [ 80.0  % ].
- Num of validation samples 1857 [ 10.0 % ].

[image]

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Total number of model parameters:1007701
Task type: regression | Evaluation metric:  rmse



self.args_gnn         = 'gcn'      
self.args_drop_ratio  = 0.5        #dropout ratio (default: 0.5)
self.args_num_layer   = 5          #number of GNN message passing layers (default: 5)
self.args_emb_dim     = 300        #dimensionality of hidden units in GNNs (default: 300)
self.args_batch_size  = 64         #input batch size for training (default: 32)
self.args_epochs      = 150        #number of epochs to train (default: 300)
self.args_num_workers = 0          #number of workers (default: 0)
self.args_lr          = 0.001      #learning rate
self.args_wdecay      = 0.001      #weight decay
self.args_pooling     = 'sum'      #pooling
```

[image]